# What is the default persistence method for Electron apps in Firebase Authentication v9?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, persistence

In Firebase v8, deleting our `Local Storage` folder for our Electron app would clear the auth persistence, but now with Firebase v9 clearing I've tried clearing `Local Storage`, `blob_storage`, and `Session Storage` - but the authentication is still persisted.

What is the default mode of persistence now? Bonus points if you can instruct on how to clear that on Electron, but I'm sure just finding the mechanism would be enough for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's IndexedDB now, apparently. I just deleted folders until I found the one that cleared the auth.